# What is the difference between lockless and non-blocking?

Tags: synchronization, locking, lock-free, nonblocking

In the context of data-structures synchronization, can someone clarify the difference between "lockless" and "non-blocking"? These terms seem to be used interchangeably by a lot of people but I'm not yet sure if there isn't some subtle difference hidden somewhere.

I mean lockless is "without locks" and non-blocking is more like guaranteeing progress. I suspect that one implies the other but not the other way around, I'm not sure.

References welcome.

Comment: "Non-blocking" is probably best thought of in terms of avoiding progress-hazards (and might even involve spin locks and threads internally).  Every function call returns in a timely fashion or returns partial work (a co-routine yield, a promise, or calls back when done).

Locking is a correctness-strategy that has has correctness-hazards and progress-hazards, such as died-while-holding-lock and amdahls-law.  

Another non-locking correctness-strategy and progress-strategy invoking commutative properties (lockless structures, immutables) might be appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locking is an access control mechanism. Whereby i mean you lock a resource when you want an exclusive access to it. Lock the door, use the room/do whatever you wish, now unlock the room for others, so that they can use it now. While the room is locked, no one else could have entered the room, thus could not have done anything.

Blocking is used for guaranteed data-retrieval, that unless you dont have data, dont come back. Keep waiting at the door/pipe/socket(basically anything) and when data is available get it and come back.

Addition--
Do not get confused by the literal english-meaning of the words, as they both can be used interchange-ably in the context you try to put them in. For example -- **locking** is like *blocking* for others to use the same resource, and **blocking** can be *locking* yourself(calling function) to the resource until data is available.

So LOCKING simply mean you capturing a resource for a specified amount time(unless you un-block it). 
And, BLOCKING is you are blocked, which means you cannot proceed further as you do not have data, to proceed or go ahead.

The way they are implemented, by changing the states of the process, and waiting for the interrupt or event to occur.

Comment: If I understood then locks are blocking?

Comment: @Helltone - Generally a lock is only blocking if someone else is already using it.

Comment: These comments are confusing to me. So you say that "lockless" means that the completion of others does not depends on self and "non-blocking" means that self completion does not depends on others. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Helltone -- there is nothing like lockless. I say again very clearly donot go by english meanings of the words, try to think afresh.

Comment: It is more confusing to say lock is only blocking, as you mixing english here with terminology. Locking means you cannot access a resource unless the resource is freed from the lock. If you are the person who have locked the resource, you can use it, if you are not the person who have locked the resource you cannot use it, unless it is freed by the person/function call which has locked the resource(CDrom). Blocking mean wait for the data to come from CDrom, unless data is received keep waiting, which means unless CDrom has a CD, with some data, keep looking for CD in the CDrom

Comment: Locking and blocking are two different concepts.

Comment: @Vivek in what they are different?

Comment: Some languages let you try to get a lock, but will return immediately if you can't get it - to be non-blocking.  

If you can call a function and it is guaranteed to keep making progress or return at a deadline then it's non-blocking.

Answer (score 3):

They're totally different.

Locking means you use some method to control file access using locks. This stops two processes writing to the same file at the same time, stops one writing while another is reading, but allows two to read at the same time.

Blocking means the method will wait for the operation to complete before returning.

**Update**

In response to the request for examples... I will try to add examples if I get time, but for now, here's an explanation of the possibilities.

We have 3 ways to perform locking:

- None
- Blocking. If the lock is unavailable, wait for it.
- Non-blocking. If the lock is unavailable, fail.

And 2 ways to perform IO:

- Blocking. Wait until the buffers are ready.
- Non-blocking. Fail if we can't read/write immediately

If we use `open()` and `read()` as normal, we get blocking IO. If we want non-blocking IO we have to pass the `O_NONBLOCK` flag to `open()`, and `read()` will then return `E_AGAIN`
instead of blocking.

By default there is no locking. We can call `fcntl()` with `F_SETLK` or `F_SETLKW` to obtain the lock. The former blocks if the lock is unavailable, the latter fails with `EACCES` or `EAGAIN`.

I think there are two possible points of confusion:

- IO can be blocking/non-blocking, locking can be blocking/non-blocking.
- Aside from data not being ready, a IO request can block because another process has the file locked.

Comment: Locking is not only used for file access, but ok I understand your answer. I'm not sure they are "totally" different, perhaps one implies the other? or in some contexts they are the same but not in general. Then my question is: which contexts?.

Comment: Sure, locking applies to all sorts of access - file access is just an easy example. They are orthogonal issues and you can have either without the other.

Comment: @Draemon "you can have either without the other". Examples would be really welcome here.

Comment: No examples yet, but an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lockless means without a locking mechanism.  Non-blocking means that a call is going to return immediately rather than waiting for some external event (such as the release of a lock, or data arriving in a buffer) to occur.  It's possible to have locks and use non-blocking calls, as for instance in the call

```
flock(fh, LOCK_SH | LOCK_NB);
```

which means "try to get a read lock, but if you can't, don't wait around for one, return immediately and tell me you couldn't".  The default behavior of `LOCK_SH` ("shared lock") without `LOCK_NB` ("non-blocking") would be to wait for lock availability.

Answer (score 1):

They can be similar, but often used in different contexts.  In the context of a data structure, they would be the same thing.  You could also use "non-blocking" in the context of IO as well, in which case it means that the function will not wait for the operation to complete before returning or that the operation is certain not to block (e.g. reading data that has already been cached).

Also, non-blocking may not imply that something is lockless.  For example, a data structure may use locks but have some non-blocking operations that don't require a lock and other blocking operations that do require one.

Answer (score 0):

A tentative answer through an example:

Consider an object (called "event") with two methods, `wait()` and `notify()`.

- Implementation 1:

  `notify()` atomically sets a boolean. `wait()` loops until the boolean is true. Both are **lockless**, but `wait()` is **blocking**.
- Implementation 2:

  `notify()` gets a lock, sets a boolean then releases the lock. `wait()` gets the lock, reads the boolean, releases the lock, all this in a loop until the boolean is true. Both are thus **lock-based**, **blocking**.
- Implementation 3:

  Initially the lock is in use. `notify()` checks a boolean and releases the lock if it's true. `wait()` gets the lock and sets the boolean to true. `notify()` is **non-blocking** (it is argueable whether it is **lockless** or not). `wait()` is **lock-based**, **blocking**.

So I would say that **non-blocking** implies **lockless**, but they are not equivalent because a **lockless** operation can still block for a condition in a loop.